# Converting a list of differently named vectors into a dataframe with unique column names in R

Tags: r

The title is wordy, but i couldn't find a solution to this problem and wanted to be as specific as possible. Is there an easy way to do the following:

```
test3 <- list('Row1'=c(a='a',b='b',c='c'), 'Row2'=c(a='d',var2='e',var3='f'))

desired dataframe
     a    b    c var2 var3
Row1 a    b    c <NA> <NA>
Row2 d <NA> <NA>    e    f
```

This article - https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-list-to-a-data-frame/ - seems to claim I can just use as.data.frame(test3), however when I do it, I obtain:

```
> as.data.frame(test3)
  Row1 Row2
a    a    d
b    b    e
c    c    f

t(as.data.frame(test3))
     a   b   c  
Row1 "a" "b" "c"
Row2 "d" "e" "f"
```

neither of which are right...

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: you can just transpose `t(as.data.frame(test3))`

Comment: this doesnt give what I'm looking for. see my EDIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with `rbindlist()` from `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
test3 <- list('Row1'=c(a='a',b='b',c='c'), 'Row2'=c(a='d',var2='e',var3='f'))
rbindlist(lapply(test3, as.list), fill=TRUE)
#    a  b  c var2 var3
# 1: a  b  c   NA   NA
# 2: d NA NA    e    f
```

The elements of your list `test3` are named character vectors - so first coercing to lists.
If you want the rownames you can do:

```
result <- setDF(rbindlist(lapply(test3, as.list), fill=TRUE))
rownames(result) <- names(test3)
result
#        a    b    c var2 var3
#   Row1 a    b    c <NA> <NA>
#   Row2 d <NA> <NA>    e    f
```

This will coerce the data.table to a dataframe and then sets the rownames.
For a data.table result you have to define an extra column for the rownames:

```
result <- rbindlist(lapply(test3, as.list), fill=TRUE)
result[, rowna := names(test3)]
result
#    a  b  c var2 var3 rowna
# 1: a  b  c   NA   NA  Row1
# 2: d NA NA    e    f  Row2
```

Comment: Is it me or do we need to use `use.names = T` as optinal argument in `rbindlist`?

Comment: @agerom It is done implicit (helptext of rbindlist() about `fill=`: "When TRUE, use.names has to be TRUE,"). Try `rbindlist(lapply(test3, as.list), fill=TRUE, use.names=FALSE)` to get an error.